# What happens if we resize images repeatedly

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, dataset

I need a dataset(image). So I downloaded images, for training purpose I resized images twice. From random sizes to (200,300), using that resized images   I resized them again to (64,64). Is there any possibility that I can face problems while training. Does a picture loss it's data when resized again and again.
can u please explain me in detail. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try downsampling one of the original images directly to 64x64, and compare it to the one you obtained by your two-step process. Do you notice any qualitative differences? That is the best way to answer your question. The answer, I suspect, depends on the method you use for downsampling.

Answer (score 0):

Images fundamentally lose their data when down sampling. If a pixel is the fundamental piece of data in an image and you remove pixels, then you have removed data. Different down sample methods lose different amounts of data. For instance a bilinear or bicubic down sample method will use multiple pixels in the larger image to generate a single pixel in the smaller image, whereas nearest neighbor downsampling uses a single pixel in the larger image to generate a single pixel in the smaller image, thereby losing more data.

Whether the down sampling will affect your training depends on more information than you have provided.